# Decorator doesn't infer type

Tags: typescript, generics, decorator, typescript-decorator

Consider following code: [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgIRABRQezAFXAgB40BDAZwgBops9DIA+KAXigG8oBtAaQhBQ4AOygBrATgBmUclQC6ALlmUIfAfKgQAHsmEATCnVwEiUAPxR+g5cIgA3VFAC+AbgBQoSMbwUA6nDAABaMJHI0PqbMbLCIyOhYJqGkqrT0URBM3BIg0ioKHu5SAK7CAMbAcDiiACIQZTgoZMCNxADCtLxauhAGRun+gSFE7bQAFAB0U2QoAOYUymTCIACUbCxLIExMY-o4AMoAtsHKk1Nghwt0M2SHEPEU7XzyTGusLABK98Uowsltz1enHcUFBUBQ31+UBK5Uq1SgY2AM1m92UHXEAmUvFo+ggFDKKDgYBaKGUoX06VQoDq+MJxNaAN4mgAZLBShUqsIgRwQWC+Q1hBRgFBGnBZiIYOyYrjaUSSRN7GQEMUIABCQp8vkyglyxoKpUqmIwjnwxFBOBXdFTCbIq6YG53B5PJnc3mazUQ4A-UQAWWaQQmTQMOEOYzWLAmAFY3e7Y5Y9kdgjawGAECAzRbaLaVjHY5rlKLxcJJeVk6n08FM1Bs7mwc5q0ZGfIPHy3O5nO53GUEJQjABBYF8gACdQaTRJxD7tAARI6gjh9NOdmNtLRVusoCBAxBIM0Vys1gB6Q9QPxLYUtITCKROFF2QllKBePExucLle2YqHABGqDXyiFQlhFmNYeTzT1vSgbQoAAak3GMO2cIA)

```
type FilterByPropType<Base, PropType> = { [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends PropType ? Key : never };
type PropsWithType<Base, PropType> = FilterByPropType<Base, PropType>[keyof Base];

function Decorator<C, K extends PropsWithType<C, (...args: any) => any>>(doSmth: (...pms: Parameters<C[K]>) => ReturnType<C[K]>) {
    return function (target: C, key: K, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<C[K] & Function>) {
        const originFunc = descriptor.value!;

        descriptor.value = function (this: C, ...args: Parameters<C[K]>) {
            return Math.random() > .5
                ? doSmth.apply(this, args)
                : originFunc.apply(this, args)
        } as C[K];
    };
}

class A {
    @Decorator<A, "method">((x, y) => y.repeat(x)) // Want to infer generic types
    method(x: number, y: string) {
        return x + y
    }
}
```

When I'm calling a decorator, I have to specify class inside of which it is applied and method name it is applied to directly as generic options:

```
@Decorator<A, "method">((x, y) => y.repeat(x)) // Want to infer generic types
```

If I won't specify them, typescript will infer `<unknown, never>` instead of `<A, "method">`.

How can I make it to infer types automatically?